# Python play again

Tags: python, loops, do-while

I am trying to add a play again y/n option but the game asks me to pick a number before asking to play again (if it were to work) and the play again option doesn't pop up.

Code:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import random
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
import random
from sys import stdout as s
from time import sleep as j
def w(print):
  for i in print:
    j(.03)
    s.write(i)
    s.flush()
  next = input()
def noinput(print):
  for i in print:
    j(.03)
    s.write(i)
    s.flush()
while True:
  num = random.randint(1, 50)
  guess = "none"

  while guess != num:
    guess = input(Fore.CYAN + "Choose a number: ")
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess == num:
      w(Fore.GREEN + "You guessed the correct number!")
      break
    else:
      w(Fore.RED + "Sorry try again")

    if guess > num:
      w("your number is too large")
      os.system('clear')
    else:
      w("your number is too small")
      os.system('clear')

  play_again = input(Fore.BLUE + "Play again? y/n: ") 
  os.system('clear')
  if play_again.lower() != ("y"):
   break
```

I would like to know why this is not working:

```
play_again = input(Fore.BLUE + "Play again? y/n: ") 
os.system('clear')
if play_again.lower() != ("y"):
 break
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not properly indented.
Every control flow statement should be followed by an additional level of indentation.

As is we cannot comment on why your code doesn't work as expected, since it does not work at all :)

Comment: thanks for letting me know ill try to properly indent it. the only error I receive is break is out of loop so ill try and see if indenting fixes it!

Comment: I am still not able to run your code. `w` is not defined somehow it could just be the `print` function. But than you clear the screen directly after printing. So there is nothing to be seen. Other than that it should work.

Comment: Also you should include all `imports` in your code so that it can be easily tested.

Comment: I forgot to include part of it hang on

Comment: It seems to work just fine. Can you explain again what you want to change?

Comment: It doesnt ask if you want to play again or not and when I put the break in, it says either its unexpectedly indented and to backspace but when I do it says its out side of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should specify the environment you run your code, such as python version, system version

however I just copied your code without change and it works fine on python3:

```
Choose a number: 49
You guessed the correct number!
Play again? y/n
```

PS: you use `print` as an argument of an function at line 10 `def w(print):`, but `print` is python's built-in function name, that will repoert an error python2, also wrong usage in python3 even no error is reported.

Comment: thanks i fixed it now i have more questions that ill post. Like I said I'm hella new to this